# Headers in angular 6 is not working property when I call HTTP.GET in my requisition with Credentials

Tags: jquery, angular, http, get

I'm trying to do a GET from my angular app to my backend and I need to set an user and password as Basic Authorization in header.

But I'm getting a logon error.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqwZM.png

Error in image above

```
OPTIONS http://MyServer/sap/opu/odata/SAP/ZHRAPP_SERVICE_TESTE_SRV/S_INFTY_0006Set('1268') 401 (Unauthorized)
```

When I do the options like:

```
const options = new RequestOptions({
  withCredentials: true,
});
```

And without pass any header. Chrome requested the user and password:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ucll0.jpg

When I put both like:

```
const options = new RequestOptions({
  withCredentials: true,
  headers: headers
});
```

The logon error still appear (401 - Unauthorized):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0ww7.png

```
buscaEndereco() {

const user = 'myUser';
const pass = 'MyPass';

const header = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa( user +  ':' + pass ),
  'Accept': 'text/html, application/json'
};

const headers = new Headers(header);

const options = new RequestOptions({
  headers: headers
});

const pernr = '1268';

this.http.get(`http://myserver.com/sap/opu/odata/SAP/ZHRAPP_SERVICE_TESTE_SRV/S_INFTY_0006Set('${ pernr }')`,
  options
)
.pipe(
  map(dados => dados.json())
)
.subscribe(
  dados => console.log('Funcionou', dados),
  error => console.log('DEU ERRO', error)
);
```

}

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong with this kind of authentication?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Ryan, please paste the exceptions as code snippets in your question, I for one dont even have access to sites like imgur

Comment: @RayanReis why you use `subscribe` here?

Comment: @FRECIA The only error is 401 - anauthorized from the server because the basic authentication in header is not working. i Edited the post with teh error.